# How to set FULL computer name to a variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

When `right clicking >Computer > Properties`, my full computer name is 50 characters.

If I `set Cname=%COMPUTERNAME%` and `echo %Cname%`, the FULL name is truncated from 50 characters down to just the Host name of 14 chars

In a batch file, how is the FULL computer name extracted?

Comment: The powershell returns the first 15 chars LF and the first 15 chars again.

Comment: show screenshot of it and block out sensitve naming if you must.

Comment: I renamed the computer to A234567890123456789212345678931234567894123456789512345678961234 Same results.

Comment: This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and) says specificalyl hostname is limited to 15 character.

Comment: I have to toggle between this and my offline computer using the same monitor and put a screen cap on a chip.  Will do in the morn.  It's 2am here...  Here is a VBS that works, I just need to call it from a batch or call a batch from the VBS https://books.google.com/books?id=h5pCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=DisplayComputerNames.vbs+Wilson&source=bl&ots=pTDtMOJgP4&sig=ACfU3U3b7nWcPSA_Hu4hk1kV1zfWVMTDvw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQwc-h84PhAhWSqp4KHZPgA3EQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=DisplayComputerNames.vbs%20Wilson&f=false

Comment: Can you provide some further information on what you're trying to do, and in what context. Please also note that NetBIOS computer names are limited to `15` characters, variables aren't, so unless you provide that context we're unable to replicate your issue. Also if the `.vbs`, which is reading a value from the registry works, what's stopping you from parsing that key from your batch file, using `reg.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is based purely on the vbscript you stated was retuning the string you require:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Pre=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet"
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set _ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "%Pre%\Control\Computername\ActiveComputerName" /V "ComputerName" 2^>Nul
')Do Set "_ActiveComputerName=%%B"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "%Pre%\Control\Computername\ComputerName" /V "ComputerName" 2^>Nul
')Do Set "_ComputerName=%%B"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "%Pre%\Services\TCPIP\Parameters" /V "HostName" 2^>Nul
')Do Set "_HostName=%%B"
Set _
```

---

Simply choose the example which outputs the string you were requiring for your purposes.

Either:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Pre=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "%Pre%\Control\Computername\ActiveComputerName" /V "ComputerName" 2^>Nul
')Do Set "ActiveComputerName=%%B"
Set ActiveComputerName
Pause
```

Else:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Pre=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "%Pre%\Control\Computername\ComputerName" /V "ComputerName" 2^>Nul
')Do Set "Computer-Name=%%B"
Set Computer-Name
Pause
```

Or:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Pre=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('
    Reg Query "%Pre%\Services\TCPIP\Parameters" /V "HostName" 2^>Nul
')Do Set "Host-Name=%%B"
Set Host-Name
Pause
```

Comment: Example 3 works.  Circumvents the NetBIOS computer name limit of 15 chars and store a top-level info variable for uses limited only by RAM and the HDD capacity. Appended to example: set "V_compName=%Host-Name% Use for whatever Variable application.

Answer (score 1):

**For the reference for Computer Name and Full computer name**

https://superuser.com/questions/640046/what-is-the-difference-between-computer-name-and-full-computer-name

**Now coming to your question, You can get your computer name with following ways:**

1. %computername%
2. net config workstation | findstr /C:"Full Computer name"
3. wmic computersystem  get name

Reference :
https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-computer-name-from-command-line/

**There is no limitation of DOS console, I have tested as below:**
[image]

Comment: All 3 of these truncate the name in a batch file.  I have seen wmic return the full name in other scripting languages, but not as shown in a batch.

Comment: The full name can be set in >Computer > properties > change settings.  This is on an offline stand-alone workstation, having the default Workgroup. No domain has been joined. There are no spaces.  The computer name looks like "Dell15c-Graphics-Workstation-Dec2017" -without the quotes

Comment: I set your name in batch file and tested.
---
set Cname=Dell15c-Graphics-Workstation-Dec2017

echo %Cname%
---
And it shows whole name on powershell.